# Use tf.train.Saver object on a predefined graph object

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph

TL;DR: Why cant we use something like `tf.saver.Save(graph=graph_obj)` to define a saver object?

---

The title mostly says it all... AFAIK, in order to link a saver-object to your graph, you need to define it like so

```py
with tf.Graph().as_default() as g_def:
    x_input_fun = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name='input')
    y_output_fun = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name='output')
    w_weights_fun = tf.get_variable('weight_set', dtype=tf.float32, shape=(5,5))
    output = tf.matmul(x_input_fun, w_weights_fun, name='pred')
    loss = tf.subtract(output, y_output_fun, name='loss')
    self.opti = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(loss, name='opti')
    g_def.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAIN_OP, self.opti)

    # Now the saver is linked to this graph when we do saver.save(...)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

And if you want to link it to the default graph, you only need to say `tf.train.Saver()` (if you have trainable/save-able variables in it of course).

But why cant we do something like: `tf.train.Saver(graph=g_def)`?

This would feel more natural to me. A similar case holds (for me) when we restore a model from a checkpoint... Even if we execute the following piece of code

```py
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('some_meta_file.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, './some_meta_file')
```

then still the `tf.default_graph()` has gained nodes from the imported meta file. I can think of reasons how it works... but now why?

EDIT:

A mistake that I made while checking the nodes of imported graphs is the following. I ran this code

```py
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('some_meta_file.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, './some_meta_file')
    print(sess.graph == tf.get_default_graph())
```

because I wanted to be sure that the default graph did not contain nodes that I just imported into the graph of the session. However, this tf.get_default_graph() is of course.. relative.. Thus in this session the default graph is actually the graph that is imported.

So this also makes it the working of the saver-object more logical. Since this object will always save/take the content of the tf.get_default_graph().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to save or restore anything, `tf.train.Saver` needs a session, and session is bound to a particular graph instance (like in your example). This means that the saver is practically meaningless without a session. I guess this was the main motivation not to have an explicit graph binding in a saver.

I think what might be interested to you is `defer_build` attribute in [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver):

> `defer_build`: If `True`, defer adding the save and restore ops to the `build()` call. In that case `build()` should be called before finalizing the graph or using the saver.

This way you can create a `tf.train.Saver` that is not bound to any graph and call `build()` later for a particular `tf.Graph` instance.

Comment: @zwep it will be done automatically, if you run `tf.train.import_meta_graph` inside `session` block. The block redefines the default graph with the supplied `graph`